# Mono NotImplementedException in X509CertificateCollection

Tags: c#, mono, x509certificate

I have a console application written in C# that I'm trying to run on Linux with mono 4.2.1 (also tried 4.4.1), but I'm getting a `NotImplementedException` when calling `X509CertificateCollection.Add()`. This is the offending code:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certFilename, "");
var clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

I have `mono-complete` installed, and tried both a standard build and Xamarin build, with the same results. I also checked I have `ca-certificates-mono` installed based on [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#notes) in the docs. I did some digging and found [this](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/7217282/) in the mono code, which suggests this functionality has been implemented, but clearly is not working for me. Am I missing part of the build/deployment process here?

Comment: Try to upgrade to Mono 4.4.1 first.

Comment: Upgraded to 4.4.1 and still the same problem.

Comment: There seems to be one `X509CertificateCollection` class in namespace `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` and one in `Mono.Security.X509`. Do both throw the exception?

Comment: I will try this code snippet with the `Mono` version later, but I need it to fit in with system library requests so I couldn't get that version to fit. Also, I'm no mono expert, but I gathered from the mono logs that was what the JIT compiler was doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a NotImplementedException then something is missing down the chain of your assembly dependencies. What I would do is check if your solution has the required dependencies for the X509Certificate installed in your GAC/BIN on debug. I hope this helps!